# Player can't move while on a moving platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code that moves the player with the moving platform. It works but the problem is that I can't move the player when the controls are disabled. Can anyone show some solutions

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if(other.gameObject == Player){
        on = true;
        Player.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
    }
}
void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
{
    on = false;
    Player.transform.parent = null;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code responsible for moving the player?

Comment: Also, show us the code for how you disable the controls.

Comment: As others people have said, it would help to have additional code presented, but as a rough idea for how to handle it is you want to add the platform's movement vector to the movement of your character when they are standing on the platform. Depending on how your movement is done, it can be as simple as adding the platform velocity to your character inside your check for standing on the platform.

Comment: `I can't move the player when the controls are disabled` ... I would agree ^^ ... so don't disable the controls?